# inserting into a list but ensuring that there isnt multiple insertions in the list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append

Ive been trying to create a part of code that takes data from an excel file then adds it into a list but only once. all other times should be ignored, ive managed to get all the data i need, just need to know how to pop unwanted duplicates. Also wondering if i should do this in a dictionary and how it would be done if i did

```
for cellObj in rows:<br>
    Lat = str(cellObj[5].value)<br>
    if 'S' in Lat:<br>
        majorCity.append(str(cellObj[3].value))<br>
        print(majorCity)<br>
    elif majorCity == majorCity:<br>
       majorCity.pop(str(cellObj[3].value))<br>
```

Comment: try the `set` object

Comment: how would you write that in mate?

Comment: @f5r5e5d set is an unordered data structure. Nick, What is your input and expected output?

Comment: input is from a column of latitude coordinates from an excel file, which i have set to out put the country the belong to, just gettting an output like ['sydney'], ['sydney'],['sydney'] but wish to one get one of each

Comment: 'Belo Horizonte', 'Belo Horizonte', 'Belo Horizonte', 'Belo Horizonte',

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set` is indeed a good way to do this:

```
>>> my_list = [1,1,2,2]
>>> my_list_no_dups = list(set(my_list))
>>> my_list_no_dups
[1, 2]
```

but it will not necessarily preserve the order of the list. If you do care about the order, you can do it like this:

```
my_list_no_dups = []
for item in my_list:
    if item not in my_list_no_dups:
        my_list_no_dups.append(item)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `set()`, it will remove duplicates from a sequence.

```
a= set()
a.add("1")
a.add("1")
print a
```

Output:

```
set(['1'])
```